How to provision VM with Oracle Linux 9 and Secure Launch
According to the documentation[3], Oracle Linux 9 is one of the supported OSes to use with Secure Launch. However, when going through the setup wizard, the option is not shown in the list (see image).

Clicking on see all images and then selecting an oracle 9 offering, presents the warning:
This image is not compatible with the selected security type. To keep Trusted launch virtual machines, select a compatible image. Otherwise, change your security type back to Standard.

How am I supposed to provision a Secure Launch VM with Oracle Linux 9?

[3] - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/trusted-launch

The documentation says Oracle Linux LVM is compatible. LVM is missing in the image name in your screenshot, but it shows in the Redhat entries. Did you pick the wrong image?

On de Learn page it lists 9.0 without the LVM (I updated the question with a screenshot), but for me it is not clear which of the several Oracle Linux 9 offerings in the Marketplace actually qualify (I expected a Microsoft-offered image to be available, but it looks like I only see images from other vendors).
